# EF6 - Lazy Loading does not work anymore

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

When I create new entity and save changes to database, I'm not able to lazy load any navigation properties.

LazyLoading and ProxyCreation are enabled on context. It has been working in past, but after refactoring, it does not work anymore (refactoring did no include refactoring of context class).

When I try to load entity, for some navigation properties I got following error: 'ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.'

Thanks

Comment: You need to use virtual property for navigation properties.

Comment: I use virtual property

Comment: how are you managing your context? Aren't you somehow closing the context after saving changes?

Comment: Even if I try to load entity, same navigation context throws exception 'ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed' immediately after loading entity

Comment: It's probably that you're using a `using` block that is disposing the context too early

Comment: No, I have DatabaseManager which is created per request using Ninject. DatabaseManager initialize context and pass to repositories for usage

Comment: im agree with the other here you are disposing the dbContext and then you are calling a navigation property which is not loaded. post your code